# R markdown not rendering when file is scripted to run

Tags: python, r, pdf, r-markdown

I have the following .Rmd file that generates a pdf the way I expect:

````
---
title: |
   \includegraphics[width=6in]{image.png} \
  \vspace{1.0in}
  \Huge \textbf{My Report}
author: "OnlyDean"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    keep_tex: true
params:
  district_name: null
  location_name: null
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{geometry}
  - \geometry{landscape, margin=0.75in}
  - \usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
  - \usepackage{caption}
  - \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}
  - \usepackage[font=Large, labelfont=bf]{caption}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
---

\newpage

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

{ MY FIRST CODE CHUNK }
```
```{r render_display, echo=FALSE}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(before = function(before, options, envir)) {
  rm(list = ls(), envir = envir)

{ THE CODE CHUNK WHERE I MAKE ALL THE KNITR CALLS }
```
````

The problem is that this script can only generate one report at a time, for a single `district_name`/`location_name` combination. I need to generate a separate pdf document for each unique `district_name`/`location_name` pair, which is hundreds. I wrote the following wrapper script in python to do that:

```
import jaydebeapi
import os
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import yaml

robjects.r.library("rmarkdown")
rmd_file = "report.Rmd"

def read_db_config(filename='db_config.yaml'):
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    parent_directory = os.path.dirname(current_directory)
    file_path_in_parent = os.path.join(parent_directory, filename)
    with open(file_path_in_parent, 'r') as stream:
        db_config = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    return db_config['database']

def connect_to_database():
    db_config = read_db_config()
    url = f"jdbc:oracle:thin:@{db_config['host']}:{db_config['port']}/{db_config['database_name']}"
    connection = jaydebeapi.connect(
        db_config['driver'],
        url,
        [db_config['username'], db_config['password']],
        db_config['driver_jar_path']
    )
    return connection

query = """MY DB QUERY"""

try:
    db_connection = connect_to_database()
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in result_set:
        district_name = row[0]
        location_name = row[1]
        params = robjects.r.list(
            district_name=district_name,
            location_name=location_name
        )
        output_file = f"{district_name}_{location_name}.pdf".replace(" ", "_")
        robjects.r.render(rmd_file, output_file=output_file, params=params)

    cursor.close()

finally:
    if db_connection:
        db_connection.close()
```

When I run this wrapper script, I get the following output in the console:
R[write to console]:

```
processing file: report.Rmd

  |......                               |  17% [setup]
```

And then the script terminates, only having gone through the loop once (I'm positive the result set is more than that) and not generating a pdf, tex, or log file.

Can anyone help me resolve this? Thanks!